# joining tables in django using query.join

Tags: sql, django, join

in django < 1.3 there was a method .join in BaseQuery model with this signature:

```
def join(self, connection, always_create=False, exclusions=(),
         promote=False, outer_if_first=False, nullable=False, reuse=None):
     """
     Returns an alias for the join in 'connection', either reusing an
     existing alias for that join or creating a new one. 'connection' is a
     tuple (lhs, table, lhs_col, col) where 'lhs' is either an existing
     table alias or a table name. The join correspods to the SQL equivalent
     of::
         lhs.lhs_col = table.col
     """
```

so to make the join all was need is something like in this example: http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/

```
# setup intial FROM clause
# OR contacts.query.get_initial_alias()
contacts.query.join((None, 'crm_contact', None, None))
# join to crm_contact_phones
connection = (
    'crm_contact',
    'crm_contact_phones',
    'id',
    'contact_id',
)
contacts.query.join(connection, promote=True)
```

now in django 1.6 the signature changed and I'm not able to that anymore:

```
def join(self, connection, reuse=None, outer_if_first=False,
         nullable=False, join_field=None):
    """
    Returns an alias for the join in 'connection', either reusing an
    existing alias for that join or creating a new one. 'connection' is a
    tuple (lhs, table, join_cols) where 'lhs' is either an existing
    table alias or a table name. 'join_cols' is a tuple of tuples containing
    columns to join on ((l_id1, r_id1), (l_id2, r_id2)). The join corresponds
    to the SQL equivalent of::

        lhs.l_id1 = table.r_id1 AND lhs.l_id2 = table.r_id2
    """
```

whenever I pass the connection with join_cols, it will fails because it asks for join_field which I don't really know what to pass for it.

Comment: I believe that is part of internal API which should not be used by us to prevent such situations. It might be simpler just to use the raw sql command.

Comment: Is the join_field `crm_contact`?

Comment: @miki725 I tried to get around it using prefetch_related but that didn't help. I want an outer left join inside the query so I can access the fields with my extra select as it is way complicated to be done without raw sql, still I need to keep the ORM results not just raw ones.
extra_order_bys='power('+str(RANK_COEFFICIENT_FOLLOW) * ( 1 - (CAST(COUNT("app_post_Streams"."stream_id") AS DOUBLE PRECISION) / CAST(%d AS DOUBLE PRECISION))), 2.0) + ' % max_followings
query=query.extra(select={'rank': extra_order_bys}).extra(order_by=['rank'])
so i join the tables then I'm free to use all their cols.

Comment: @JohnMee let's assume it is yea. I tried passing it, or passing its relation. it is many to many field.